# As long as tap hold - do function, if !tap - stop function

Tags: jquery, mobile

I am actually adjusting my website to mobile devices and have a problem with converting hover events into something mobile-friendly: I use for certain functions the hover event as "trigger". And now I don´t know how to convert a hover event into a mobile-frindly event. I know the taphold event in my plugin (jquery finger) but that only triggers once and doesn´t tell when the tap ceased to be hold. I would need something like:

```
$("selector").on("as long as tap is hold", function () {

});
```

And for another case I´d need something similar, the only difference is I want something similar to "mouseleave" - just for mobile devices (when user doesn´t hold anymore).

Last but not least it should work for delegated events, too.

jQuery (for PCs):

```
var myInterval;
var i = 0;
var link;
$(".postimagepic").hover(function () {
    link = $(this).attr("src");
    i = 0;
    myInterval = setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'somephp.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'user':'loooook',
                'topost':link
            },
            success: function() {

            }
        });
        i++;
        if(i == 30) {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
        }
    }, 1000);
}, function () { //That´s why I need to know when not holding anymore
    clearInterval(myInterval);
});
```